# $_POST request works with postman but not in android app

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I've been on this problem for a while now currently trying to convert my php scripts to PDO but the $_POST are always giving me null when ran through isset(). My code in android works fine with my other scripts but this one only works in postman when I change the $_POST to $_REQUEST on each item and the links also look different. Its also worth mentioning that onResponse and onFailure are not receiving/printing any messages to.

**Postman URL**

```
http://123.456.7.89/Database/register.php?username=asdfasdf&password=lj4ioidfoislkjsf&email=jalenpauloiudf&tece=true&profilePicPath=aksdfjlakjdsfl&tokenId=as89gwbeg98sd
```

**Current URL**

```
http://123.456.7.89/Database/register.php
```

**Script**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "password";
$dbname = "Database";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $termsOfService = $_POST['termsOfService'];
    $profilePicPath = $_POST['profilePicPath'];
    $tokenId = $_POST['tokenId'];
    $userId = uniqId();

    //converting data
    $termsOfService = $termsOfService ? 'true' : 'false';

    //Username check
    $emailForQuery = "%" . $_POST['email'] . "%";
    $userIdForQuery = "%" . $userId . "%";
    $usernameCheckQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT email, userId FROM users WHERE email LIKE ? OR userId LIKE ? LIMIT 1");
    $usernameCheckQuery->execute([$emailForQuery, $userIdForQuery]); 
    $usernameCheckQuery->fetch();

    if ($usernameCheckQuery->rowCount() == 0) {//username doesnt exist
        $usernameCheckQuery->closeCursor();

        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(userId, username, password, email, termsOfService, profilePicPath, tokenId) 
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query->execute([$userId, $username, $hashedPassword, $email, $termsOfService, $profilePicPath, $tokenId]);
        $query->closeCursor();

        header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
        $resArray = ['success' => true, 'userId' => $userId];
        echo json_encode($resArray);

    } else { //username exists
        $usernameCheckQuery->closeCursor();
        connectionError("username already exists");
    }
        
} catch(PDOException $e) {    
    connectionError();
}

function connectionError($message = "database connection error") { //sending response
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $resArray = ['success' => false, 'message' => $message];
    echo json_encode($resArray);
    $conn = null;
}
```

?>

**Android post data**

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register.php")
fun signUpUser(@Field("username") username: String,
               @Field("password") password: String,
               @Field("email") email: String,
               @Field("termsOfService") termsOfService: Boolean,
               @Field("profilePicPath") profilePicPath: String,
               @Field("tokenId") tokenId: String): Call<ResponseLoginOrSignUp>
```

My guess is it has to do with the urls but then again the response isn't sending.

If any additional code is needed please let me know and ill add it, thanks.

**ANSWER!!!**
Here's my conclusion, I had a domain that wasn't properly secure and needed to add ssl to my hosting domain as well as a custom domain. For the ssl I used cloudflare for anyone looking for free ssl since it took me a while to find a proper site. Also switch http to https in the url showcased in android studio

Comment: The postman URL is http (vs https), and the parameters are being sent as `GET` (in the URL) instead of `POST` (in the body).

Comment: @JakeLee I made some changes that I had made while I was trying out other solutions one was the url, for your second solution are your talking about the postman url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try changing the `Http` to `https`

Then I recommend using android volley to post requests check android documentation

Comment: Im a couple days late but you were somewhat correct, I needed to change the http to https but after I added ssl to my hosting domain.

Comment: This link no longer works..

Answer (score 0):

use in android manifest
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: I put my url in a network_security_config.xml file and added it to manifest that way, I tried your solution on top of it but no luck.